# How do I pass arguments to an objects function without a crash

Tags: swift, xcode, function, object, arguments

I'm trying to move the logic of a `viewController` to a `view model` but for some reason it always crashes, saying `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I constantly get this error no matter what code I try to move, so I must be doing something fundamentally wrong. Here's a sample of the code I have in the `viewController`:

```
var recipesViewModel: RecipesViewModel! //VIEW MODEL CLASS REFERENCE


var recipeCategory = recipesViewModel.transformToUpperCase(dataRecieverStringRecipeView: "testString")
```

Then in the `view model`class:

```
func transformToUpperCase(dataRecieverStringRecipeView: String) -> String {
    var recipeCategory = dataRecieverStringRecipeView
    var prefixRecipeCategory = recipeCategory.prefix(1).uppercased()
    var dropFirstRecipeCategory = recipeCategory.dropFirst()
    var upperCasedRecipeCategory = prefixRecipeCategory + dropFirstRecipeCategory
    return upperCasedRecipeCategory
}
```

...it translates the string to have an uppercase letter as its first letter.

The code works perfectly fine when everything is in the `view model`, but as soon I move it to another class and call the function through an object it crashes. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you instantiating an object?  var recipesViewModel: RecipesViewModel! doesn't create a new object.

Comment: As an aside, this is a really good example of why it's best to avoid force unwrapping with `!` wherever possible, because it forces you to handle that the object might not exist (or forces you make sure one does exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to fix your view model class reference

**Line to change:**

```swift
var recipesViewModel: RecipesViewModel!
```

---

**Replacement Line:**

```
var recipesViewModel = RecipesViewModel()
```

---

This line of code will properly declare/create `recipesViewModel` as an object of class `RecipesViewModel`.

Hope that resolves your inquiry!

Answer (score 0):

`var recipesViewModel: RecipesViewModel!` does not instantiate a new object.  Put the category function back in your RecipesViewModel class, then change the variable declaration to:

**Declaration**

```
var recipesViewModel: RecipesViewModel!
```

---

**Later on**

```
recipesViewModel = RecipesViewModel() //or whatever initializer you need.
```

---

**Edit**

As rmaddy pointed out: you probably can ditch the ! and use `var recipesViewModel: RecipesViewModel = RecipesViewModel()` instead if you don't have any failable initializers or this isn't a runtime injected property and just put it as a 1-liner:

```
var recipesViewModel: RecipesViewModel = RecipesViewModel()
```

Comment: The use of `: RecipesViewModel!` is unnecessary. Even if you do explicitly put the type, using `!` is really pointless if you are initializing the value at the same time.

Comment: @rmaddy true, unless they have a failable initializer and aren't telling us about it lol.  Trying not to add to many additional concepts to the question.

Comment: If the initializer is failable then the variable should be declared as optional (`?`), not implicitly unwrapped (`!`).

Comment: @rmaddy What if they know it won't fail and it's just easier to implicitly unwrap it?  People do this all the time.  It's not that weird.  I just stuck with how they phrased their original question.  You don't have to explain this to me.  We don't know the context.

Comment: Oh, snap! I completely missed that part! Thanks a lot for all of your help guys, it worked like a charm!!! :D And thanks for taking the time!